# Can we get an array of all storyboard views

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I'm developping application in Swift.
This application has many view and I would like to put a UIProgressView on all views

Can we get an array of all storyboard views ?

for exemple  :

```
    self.progressBar = UIProgressView(progressViewStyle: .Bar)
    self.progressBar?.center = view.center
    self.progressBar?.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 20, width: view.frame.width, height: CGFloat(1))
    self.progressBar?.progress = 1/2
    self.progressBar?.trackTintColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor();
    self.progressBar?.tintColor = UIColor.redColor();

    var arrayViewController : [UIViewController] = [...,...,...]

    for controller in arrayViewController {
        controller.view.addSubview(self.progressBar)
    }
```

Thank you

Ysée

Comment: No, we can't get ViewControllers from Storyboard. You can instantiate them if it's needed. You can see how it works https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/UsingViewControllersinYourApplication/UsingViewControllersinYourApplication.html

Comment: Your title/description say view but your code says view controller. They are not the same thing. Suppose you have 20 view controllers in the storyboard, would you want to add a progress view to all 20 of them, even though only one is instantiated and visible and the other 19 are not? That is what you are saying you want to do. Describe your problem, rather than what you think the solution might be. And your problem is not that you want to add  a progress view to *all* the views or view controllers, your problem is probably that you want to add the progress to the *currently displayed* view?

Comment: Ok thank you for your help ! I will go to choose to put the ProgressBar in the viewWillAppear if there are an operation in progress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that what you really want is to have the progress displayed on every view IF there is an operation in progress.

There are many ways to do that (using delegation, NSNotificationCenter, …) but the easiest I can think of would be to rely on viewWillAppear

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    // Check if there's an operation in progress and add progressView if relevant
}
```

For the user, it will effectively look like you added the progress view to all views.

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a base class that has a `lazy stored property`  of type `UIProgressView` ? Optionally you can have two methods `setProgressViewHidden(hidden : Bool)` in order to easily show and hide the progress view and `setProgress(progress : Float)` to update the progress. Then all your view controllers can subclass this base class and conveniently interact with the progress view.

```
    class ProgressViewController : UIViewController {

         lazy var progressView : UIProgressView = {
            [unowned self] in

            var view = UIProgressView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 20, self.view.frame.size.width, 3))
            view.progress = 0.5
            view.trackTintColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
            view.tintColor = UIColor.redColor()

            self.view.addSubview(view)

            return view
        }()
    }
```

To read more about lazy stored properties, check: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html